# Difference in environment when using 'docker build' or 'docker run'

Tags: docker, conda

I am starting to learn Docker, and I ran into some behavior I could not understand.

I want to use `conda` inside my Docker container, but when using `docker build .` I ran into the error `/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found`. After some investigation, I think I found the problem; `conda` is not listed in the environment variable `PATH`. My simplified `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
RUN env
RUN conda info
```

The resulting environment variables do not show any reference to `conda`. However, when I use `docker run -it continuumio/anaconda3`, and then run the command `env` there, my `PATH` does contain references to `conda`.

I think solving or understanding the discrepancy between the behavior of the `docker run` and `docker build` commands will (help me) solve my initial problem. Does anyone know what causes the difference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3/dockerfile):

There's a line:

```
echo "conda activate base" >> ~/.bashrc
```

I believe it is registering the environment variables.

When you run container `conda activate base` command is executed, as a part of `.bashrc` script. Here's why: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work

On build stage the only thing happens is `echo` command writes to `.bashrc` file.

But you must **not** understand *build stage* as a build on your machine. The base image was built once by someone else ("upstream build") and you only fetching a resulting filesystem to run your build over it ("downstream build").

That's why you can't rely on `ENV` declaration in base Dockerfile.

There's a technique how the upstream build can affect the dowstream build with [ONBUILD directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild), but it's not the case for your images.

It's hard to answer why the resulting filesystem for anaconda3 doesn't contain some environment variables defined, and why miniconda has them. This images are very different, and diagnosing a build stage scripts is not easy at all.

Comment: Hi astef, thanks for your reply. It helped me understand better the sequence of events when using conda build. However, I am not sure if it is the cause of my issue.   I think the line `ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH` sets the path variable, and `conda activate base` should activate the environment when the container is run. I just tried the same with [miniconda](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3/dockerfile) and that works fine with both `build` and `run`, but I am not sure why.

Comment: You're right about `ENV`, but it only runs during upstream build. When you build your container, you're basically fetching the resulting filesystem of that upstream build. I can't say why exactly the filesystem is different for miniconda, but I can confirm they are VERY different.